# MATLAB how to plot a discrete function without vertical lines, only levels

Tags: matlab, plot

I have something like this:

```
t = [-1 0 1 2 3 4 5];
ft= [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 1];
```

I want to plot only horizontal levels high\low without vertical lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the vertical lines, it's really simple to just use the `stairs(x,t)` function. Otherwise you can create your own function that deals with pairs of points to generate lines and plot them all individually using `hold on`.

```
function stairs2(x,y)
    hold on;
    for i=1:length(x)-1
        plot(x(i:i+1),[y(i) y(i)]);
    end
    hold off;
end
```

Then just call `stairs2(x,t)` as per your example above, and set appropriate zoom/axes.

Alternately, this is a different way that only uses ONE call to plot:

```
function stairs2(x,y)
    for i=1:length(x)-1
        A(:,i) = [x(i) x(i+1)];
        B(:,i) = [y(i) y(i)];
    end
    plot(A,B,'b');
end
```

Comment: ok this do that, but creates too many object to plot if the size of the array is large! For arrays of 4000 elements it plots 3999 objects, is very slow and difficult to use if i want to save the handles, associate a tag etc.. is possible that matlab do not have a built-in function like stairs without vertical lines? :(

Comment: Even an internal MATLAB function would need to have 4000 individual line elements. I'm betting that you are not viewing all 4000 lines simultaneously anyway, because you would just use regular plot then with data that fine. If you are just trying to view a small portion of the data, then just plot that portion only with `stairs2(x(i1:i2),t(i1:i2))` where `i1` is your starting index, and `i2` is the final index.

Comment: if you plot multiple lines for example:

x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

figure
plot(x,y1,x,y2)

you plot two lines but create one object!

Comment: See my edits to the answer. I added an alternate way that might be what you want. Everything is handled with just ONE call to plot(...), but each line receives unique color properties by default.

Comment: yes, this will work, thanks. Try the method with NaNs!

Comment: That works too, but it adds alot of data to your arrays. Are you doing that by hand for a set of 4000 points? If you're worried about the line colors being different you can quickly hardcode it with the 3rd parameter in `plot`.

Comment: For consider the last value y(N) you should take the entire length(x) but is necessary the value of x(N+1).. a boundary condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `stem` plot instead:

```
stem(x,y,'LineStyle','none','Marker','_')
```